# The Javascript error message show str.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, str-replace, console.log

I have a problem returning a string where the value "cheese" is replaced with "jam". My scenario is first starting with I default values of cheese and mushrooms to be selected. If I want to select Cheese,Tomatoes,Mushrooms, console log I need the value "cheese" is replaced with "jam", and the console log result should be "jam,tomatoes,mushrooms". When I clicked the check value button, the errors message show me `str.replace is not a function` in the console log.

Below is my sample coding:

```js
$('#select_multiple').multiselect()
var data="cheese,mushrooms";
var dataarray=data.split(",");
$("#select_multiple").val(dataarray);
$("#select_multiple").multiselect("refresh");   

function check_value(){
    var str = $('#select_multiple').val();  
    var abc = str.replace("cheese", "jam"); 
    console.log(abc);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />

</head>
<body>

<select id="select_multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<button onclick="check_value();">Check Value</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to alert variable `str` to check values, it got values. Just cannot console log the values. Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of that str value? A simple string, or a string array?

Comment: I think it is string array

Comment: replace will only work for string not for string array, you can join the array to a string then after replace cnvert it back to array using split

Comment: `const abc =  $('#select_multiple').val().map(val => val.replace("cheese","jam"))`

Comment: @sojin May I know using which method string array convert to string? For example I want to result show cheese,mushrooms

Comment: `array.join()` will convert string array to string, and `string.split(',')` will convert string to array based on the ','

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are getting str as an array. You need to use for loop to replace the string that you want. see below example

```js
$('#select_multiple').multiselect()
var data="cheese,mushrooms";
var dataarray=data.split(",");
$("#select_multiple").val(dataarray);
$("#select_multiple").multiselect("refresh");   

function check_value(){
    var str = $('#select_multiple').val(); 
    for(var i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
       str[i] = str[i].replace('cheese', 'jam');
      }    
      console.log(str)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />

</head>
<body>

<select id="select_multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<button onclick="check_value();">Check Value</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is really funny that we have almost the same answer :-)

Comment: yeah, I think you copied my style.

Comment: @JaxPatel I don't think so ;-)

Answer (score 0):

that's because str is an array. that's why you still have to iterate the variable...

```js
$('#select_multiple').multiselect()
var data="cheese,mushrooms";
var dataarray=data.split(",");
$("#select_multiple").val(dataarray);
$("#select_multiple").multiselect("refresh");   

function check_value(){
    var str = $('#select_multiple').val();  
    const abc = []
    str.forEach((s) => {
      abc.push(s.replace("cheese", "jam"));   
    })
    
    
    console.log(abc);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />

</head>
<body>

<select id="select_multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
<button onclick="check_value();">Check Value</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```